# hibernate, table per class inheritance, different key column names, nee many-to-one collection

Tags: hibernate, inheritance, cascading-deletes

here are my requirements:

1. I have an existing db scheme which I cannot change.
2. I have one parent table and several child tables.
3. All child tables have key columns of same format but different names.
4. The concrete set of child tables differs for different installations.
5. For reference integrity sake I need all child entities removed when the parent entity is removed.
6. I **don't** need this cascade removal being managed by Hibernate, I control the removal myself by means of some **delete()** method.

So my possible solution shall look like the following:

1. I inherit all children classes from one superclass or interface, say **Child**
2. In the parent entity class I add @OneToMany field of type **Set**
3. When the parent entity is removed I call **delete()** for all children.

Solutions that would not work:

1. The *Table per concrete class* inheritance strategy would not work, since key columns in child tables have different names, this is not supported by hibernate.
2. Adding a @OneToMany field to parent for each child table would not work since the set of child tables differs for each installation. So they must not be explicitly references in the parent.

Comment: I don't think your solution will work. But anyway: what's your question?

Comment: To JB Nizet: I need the solution that works. I listed these bad solution just to prevent anybody proposing them to me.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only solution is to have each installation provide a list of all the child classes, and have a method that loops through these classes, select all the instances who have the soon-to-be-deleted parent, and remove them :

```
public void deleteAllChildren(Parent p) {
    List<Class<?>> classes = getListOfChildClassesFromSomewhere();
    for (Class<?> clazz : classes) {
        String hql = "select c from " + clazz.getName() + " where c.parent = :parent";
        Query q = session.createQuery(hql).setParameter("parent", parent);
        List<Object> children = (List<Object>) q.list();
        for (Object child : children) {
            session.delete(child);
        }
    }
}
```

You could also use a delete HQL query directly, but this will bypass the session.

If each sublcass references the parent using a different field/property name, then transform the list of child classes into a `Map<Class<?>, String>`, where the String value is the parent field/property name for the child class.

If you have the option to make all the children inherit a single @MappedSuperClass annotated class, where the parent field is declared and mapped, you could do a single query that would return all the children :

```
select child from ChildMappedSuperClass child where child.parent = :parent
```

But since Java only supports single inheritance, it might not be an option.